# passing an array to web-service php nusoap

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, wsdl, nusoap

i have a problem with passing an array to a web-service function that i created with php and nusoap.
the problem is that i guess i'm doing something wrong.. i suspect that the problem is in the function or in my client side. when i send an array it doesn't go into the function i registered with the web-service. i only get response of empty array when i call the web-service.
i hope someone can help me here.
thanks.

**EDIT:** I managed to fix it. i forgot to build a struct for the request.

**server side:**

```
<?php 
//include nusoap
require_once('c:\\wamp\\www\\nusoap.php');
//create server instance
$server = new soap_server();
//configure wsdl
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespaces = 'urn:GetArr';
$server->configureWSDL('GetArr','urn:GetArr');
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Product',
'complexType',
'struct',
'all',
'',
array(
'name' => array('name' => 'name', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
'code' => array('name' => 'code', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
'price' => array ('name' => 'price', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
'quantity' => array ('name' => 'quantity', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
'total_price' => array('name' => 'total_price', 'type' => 'xsd:int')
));

//this is what i was missing 
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'ArrayReq',
'complexType',
'struct',
'all',
'',
array(
'name' => array('name' => 'name', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
'code' => array('name' => 'code', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
'price' => array ('name' => 'price', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
'quantity' => array ('name' => 'quantity', 'type' => 'xsd:int')
));

//until here.

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'ProductArray',
'complexType',
'array',
'',
'SOAP-ENC:Array',
array(),
array(
array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:Product[]')),
'tns:Product');

//function that get and return values
function GetTotalPrice ($proArray) {
$temparray = array();
$temparray[] = array('name' => $proArray['name'], 'code' => $proArray['code'], 'price' => $proArray['price'], 'quantity' 
=> $proArray['quantity'], 'total_price' => $proArray['quantity'] * $proArray['price']);

return $temparray;
    };
//register the method
$server->register('GetTotalPrice',
array('proArray' => 'tns:ArrayReq'),// and this line also.  
array('return' => 'tns:ProductArray'),
'urn:GetArr',
'urn:GetArr#GetTotalPrice',
'rpc',
'encoded',
'Get the product total price'
);
//run the service
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$server->service($post);

?>
```

**client side**

```
<?php
//include nusoap
require_once('c:\\wamp\\www\\nusoap.php');
ini_set ('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);

$arr['name'] = "GoPro";
$arr['code'] = "245";
$arr['price'] =70;
$arr['quantity'] = 4;  

  $sClient = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/nusoap/comserv.php?wsdl','wsdl','','','','');
  $response = $sClient->call('GetTotalPrice',array($arr),'','', false,true);


$error = $sClient->getError();
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}

if ($sClient->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    echo ($response);
    echo "</pre>";
}
else {
    $error = $sClient->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    }
if ($response != "" || NULL){
    echo "<h2>Respond</h2><pre>";
    print_r ($response);
    echo "</pre>";
    }
}

?>
```

**this is the output(respond)**

```
Respond

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [code] => 
            [price] => 
            [quantity] => 
            [total_price] => 0
        )

)
```

**EDIT:**
this is the fixed output.

Respond

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => GoPro
            [code] => 245
            [price] => 70
            [quantity] => 4
            [total_price] => 280
        )

)
```

Comment: ok so i fixed it. i added comments so anyone can see what i added in order to make it work..

Answer (score 0):

ok so i fixed it. i added comments so anyone can see what i added in order to make it work..

i needed to make a struct for the request so my function will know the array type. also fixed it in the function registration.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @HashemQolami I think this post should be subject to editing, but not deleting (I'm seeing a lot of people voted to delete). Especially since the OP found the fix and answered his own question. He might just need to post an example of code he wrote to get it to work, but otherwise I don't see anything wrong with it.